# difficulty copying views in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm not sure what could be the issue, basically have a view in SQL SERVEr, I need to copy a SELECT statement from it, however, upon selecting some text and right clicking on it - the COPY selection is greyed out. I also cannot do CTRL + C.

Are views limited in number of characters? What is going on?

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem.   Copy and Ctrl+C both work fine for me.   Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: @TabAlleman - i have 3 other views identical to this one with slightly different where clauses. And they all work except this one

Comment: @TabAlleman added screenshot

Comment: are you in the right database and have permissions?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu -  yes I am certain everything is good

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to get the code for the view would be to right click the view in the object explorer and select

script view as --> Create to --> New Query Editor Window